# Cannot find module "."

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, firebase-admin

## Problem

Hi, i am trying to configure my firebase-admin in my Ionic 2 app. The code looks like the following (note I left out the private-key):

```
 admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert({
        projectId: "jobjack-28894",
        clientEmail: "firebase-adminsdk-j8y48@jobjack-28894.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      }),
      databaseURL: "https://jobjack-28894.firebaseio.com"
    })
```

### Things I have tried

- I have installed the defaultable.js module. Not sure why it is required. I think it might be some dependency on firebase-admin

## Error

I get the following result when the application runs.

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."
at webpackMissingModule (defaultable.js:49)
at Object.workaround_require (defaultable.js:49)
at require (defaultable.js:77)
at server.js:9
at defaulter (defaultable.js:83)
at defaultable (defaultable.js:63)
at good (defaultable.js:174)
at Object.<anonymous> (server.js:5)
at Object.<anonymous> (server.js:240)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap fad59d6ced6383582390:54)
```

Any suggestions. Been looking around for a similar error but can't find anything like this. Been trying to debug it but no luck.

My package.json looks like the following:

```js
{
  "name": "sidemenu_ionic",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "config": {
    "ionic_webpack": "./webpack.config.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve --dev",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build --prod",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build --prod",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "prod": "ionic-app-scripts serve --prod"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "1.0.16",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "dns": "^0.2.2",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "firebase": "^4.8.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.7.0",
    "ionic-angular": "nightly",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "process": "^0.11.10",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "nightly",
    "rollup-plugin-replace": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: Admin SDK cannot be used in client-side frameworks like Ionic.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Hiranya, that clears it up.  So I was trying to seed the database with a admin user when the app gets initialised. So I removed the admin reference from the angular app and added a node prescript and that seems to work a 100%. Thank you